# I'm getting error while trying to bringup turtlebot3(ROS2 Foxy, Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)

Tags: raspberry-pi4, ros2

ROS2 Foxy, downloaded SBC setup from official site. Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Here's the error code:

```
ros2 launch turtlebot3_bringup robot.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/2023-04-27-11-02-20-355271-ubuntu-3669
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : turtlebot3_burger.urdf
/opt/ros/foxy/share/hls_lfcd_lds_driver/launch/hlds_laser.launch.py:46: UserWarning: The parameter 'node_executable' is deprecated, use 'executable' instead
  Node(
/opt/ros/foxy/share/hls_lfcd_lds_driver/launch/hlds_laser.launch.py:46: UserWarning: The parameter 'node_name' is deprecated, use 'name' instead
  Node(
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [3671]
[INFO] [hlds_laser_publisher-2]: process started with pid [3673]
[INFO] [turtlebot3_ros-3]: process started with pid [3675]
[hlds_laser_publisher-2] [INFO] [1682593340.839127617] [hlds_laser_publisher]: Init hlds_laser_publisher Node Main
[hlds_laser_publisher-2] [INFO] [1682593340.840464111] [hlds_laser_publisher]: port : /dev/ttyUSB0 frame_id : base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-1] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link base_link had 5 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link caster_back_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link imu_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link base_scan had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link wheel_left_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link wheel_right_link had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1682593340.859633235] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1682593340.860069770] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1682593340.860150825] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1682593340.860185825] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_back_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1682593340.860215103] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1682593340.860242362] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1682593340.860271306] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [INFO] [1682593340.863684033] [turtlebot3_node]: Init TurtleBot3 Node Main
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [INFO] [1682593340.864748251] [turtlebot3_node]: Init DynamixelSDKWrapper
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [INFO] [1682593340.867532980] [DynamixelSDKWrapper]: Succeeded to open the port(/dev/ttyACM0)!
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [INFO] [1682593340.873247826] [DynamixelSDKWrapper]: Succeeded to change the baudrate!
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [ERROR] [1682593340.907558905] [turtlebot3_node]: Failed connection with Devices
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [INFO] [1682593340.909686230] [turtlebot3_node]: Add Motors
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [INFO] [1682593340.910015358] [turtlebot3_node]: Add Wheels
[turtlebot3_ros-3] [INFO] [1682593340.910190153] [turtlebot3_node]: Add Sensors
[turtlebot3_ros-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
[turtlebot3_ros-3]   what():  could not create publisher: rcl node's context is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.11/src/rcl/node.c:441
[ERROR] [turtlebot3_ros-3]: process has died [pid 3675, exit code -6, cmd '/home/ubuntu/turtlebot3_ws/install/turtlebot3_node/lib/turtlebot3_node/turtlebot3_ros -i /dev/ttyACM0 --ros-args --params-file /home/ubuntu/turtlebot3_ws/install/turtlebot3_bringup/share/turtlebot3_bringup/param/burger.yaml'].
```

I tried to "resetup" OpenCR, but it didn't help, also tried to delete 'burger.yaml'

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for ages and found that I'd copied the wrong URL for the openCL firmware. The documentation is based on ROS1 and states `wget https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR-Binaries/raw/master/turtlebot3/ROS1/latest/opencr_update.tar.bz2`  when really I should have used `wget https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR-Binaries/raw/master/turtlebot3/ROS2/latest/opencr_update.tar.bz2`